# String from object does not equal string from the same object in an ArrayList

Tags: java, string, object, arraylist, methods

I'm building a catalogue using an ArrayList to hold an object called boot.

I haverun into a problem with one of the methods in my catalogue class. The method is supposed to run through the catalogue and find the boot object with the matching ID (A string value).

The catalogue is filled with these objects; like this:

```
Boot boot1 = new Boot("Extreme Hiking Boot", "A123456", "For extreme terrains", "Khaki", "Canvas", "For all terrains", 65.50, 100, 5);
Boot boot2 = new Boot("Casual Hiker", "B123456", "A hiking boot for the casual person", "Brown", "Leather", "Rocky", 55.95, 200, 3);
Boot boot3 = new Boot("Broken Boot", "Y123456","A broken boot", "Yellow", "Plastic", "Soft Ground", 110.45, 400, 1);
```

Here's the method that's causing problems:

```
public double getPriceForProduct(String ID){
    double price = -1.0;

    for(Boot b : catalogue){
        if(b.getID().equals(ID)){
            price = b.getPrice();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("We don't have a boot with that ID in stock.");
            System.out.println(b.getID()+"\n\n");
        }
    }
    return price;
}
```

It returns this to my console:

```
We don't have a boot with that ID in stock.
B123456


We don't have a boot with that ID in stock.
Y123456


We don't have a boot with that ID in stock.
A123456


We don't have a boot with that ID in stock.
Y123456
```

I have a method that uses the same advanced for loop set up in another method that works fine at comparing doubles.

I am confused as to why this advanced for loop is not working.

Comment: And what is the value of `ID`?

Comment: You are going through the loop, and doing the if/else for every element in the loop .. so, when you pass A123456 it would set the price for it, but still print it can't find the other two ... you need to print you didn't find it only AFTER you've looked at every instance

Comment: what exactly is the issue? you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: To be able to help, we have to know what the value of `ID` is and what `getID()` does or how it does what its supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 for(Boot b : catalogue){
    if(b.getID().equals(ID)){
        price = b.getPrice();
    }
    else{ ...
    }
}
return price;
```

Point is: if you **found** something ... you should return immediately!

Assume the first "boot" matches; then you remember that price to return. Then you continue the loop ... and the second, third, ... boots will all **not** match; and print that message to you. You could rewrite your method like:

```
public double getPriceForProduct(String ID){
for(Boot b : catalogue){
    if(b.getID().equals(ID)){
        return b.getPrice();
    }
}
System.out.println("We don't have a boot with that ID in stock.");
System.out.println(ID +"\n\n");
return -1;
```

But that is not really a good solution: you really don't want that some **search** method puts up user messages. Instead, the code that **calls** this method checks the result; and if -1 comes back, it knows that no boots were found; and can give a message.

And for the record: floating point numbers come with subtle rounding and precision problems; and as you are in the learning phase; I would rather recommend to go with `int` whole number prices! Beyond that, the other answer has a good point: if you heard about exceptions, then rather throw an exception ("no boots found"); instead of using a "special" return value to indicated "no boots found"!

Comment: Like for stating that `double` type for prices isn't a good idea.

Comment: You are welcome ... and I liked your mentioning of exceptions; so I should honor that, too!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your solution worked. I will also be sure to include exceptions in the method. I was testing the code and put the print line there as a temporary error message.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your search loop as @okaram mentioned correctly. This should fix it:

```
public double getPriceForProduct(String ID){
  for(Boot b : catalogue){
    if(b.getID().equals(ID)){
      return b.getPrice();
    }
  }

  System.out.println("We don't have a boot with that ID in stock:\n");
  System.out.println(ID+"\n\n");

  return -1.0;
}
```

If you want to have more "clean code", then throw an exception (instead of printing to console and returning a magic value).

Answer (score -2):

**Try Like this:**

```
public double getPriceForProduct(String ID){
double price = -1.0;
boolean flag=true;

for(Boot b : catalogue){
    if(b.getID().equals(ID)){
        price = b.getPrice();
        flag=false;
        break;
    }}
  if(flag==true){
       System.out.println("We don't have a boot with that ID in stock.");
       System.out.println(ID+"\n\n"); }

 return price;
  }
```

**//For each ID executing either if or else so .. change like that it may work!!**

Comment: This won't even compile (and if it did it would *always* print the message)

Comment: You need to relax and write the code because there errors in there

Comment: I can't get you @YoungMillie

Comment: After the editing you removed some. But you still have this: `flage` instead of this: `flag`. Also what kind of `b` are you using here `b.getID()` because he has three `b` in the catalog.

Comment: Also this solution is unnecessarily complicated - why do you need that `boolean` (and `if(flag==true)` is verbose)? Further the way this answers is written is rather poor form, it doesn't explain what the issue was and just shows some code which *should* work (and both the text and code formatting is off)

Comment: By the way this still does not compile - `b` does not exist outside the `for` loop

Comment: Seriously: dont throw such answers at newbies.